# inserting data into database with condition/ codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am a beginner in CodeIgniter and I want to insert a data in codeigniter with a where clause. Something like a query like this:

```
insert into tbl_check_up (bill_id) values ("bill_id") where check_up_id = "'.$check_up_id.'" ;
```

how can i convert it into codeigniter

Here is my codeigniter model:

```
var $tbl_check_up = 'tbl_check_up';

public function save_bill_checkup($check_up_id,$data) {
        $this->db->insert($this->tbl_check_up,$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function bill_id() {
     $check_up_id = $this->input->post('check_up_id');
     $data1 = array(
            'bill_id'   => $bill_id
         );
     $insert1 = $this->billing_model->save_bill_checkup($check_up_id,$data1);
}
```

Comment: are you Updating or Inserting, because i believe there is no INSERT WHERE in mysql. COrrect me if im wrong

Comment: How can you add with where condition seems you are updating not inserting

Comment: @tomexsans Pachlangia  ok i go with update. can you convert my query above ?. i am a beginner in CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of insert, use update query.

```
$data = array(
           'bill_id'   => $bill_id
        );

$this->db->where('check_up_id', $check_up_id);
$this->db->update('tbl_check_up ', $data);
```